# JavaScript setTimeout runs fine on some object types by not others?

Tags: javascript, object, settimeout

This might be best explained with a code example...

```
Object_A = {
  testLoop:function(){
             log("running");
             setTimeout(Object_A.testLoop, 1000);
           }
};

Object_B = function(){
  this.testLoop= function(){
    log("running");
    setTimeout(this.testLoop(), 1000);
  }
}

Object_A.testLoop(); // logs message to console every 1000ms, as you would expect

var objB = new Object_B();
objB.testLoop(); // runs infinitely at once (no 1000ms interval) until "Maxium call stack size exceeded"
```

Why is it that the loop works fine in a static object but not in a "class-like" object that declares a generating function?

(on a sidenote: what it the correct name for these two types of object? I keep saying "satic" and "non-static" objects, but I feel like that's incorrect.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are first-class citizens in JavaScript. Given a function defined like this:

```
function foo()
{
    return 0;
}
```

There is a difference between this:

```
var result = foo();
```

and this:

```
var result = foo;
```

The first one invokes the function named `foo` and assigns the value returned by that invocation to `result`. In this case, `result` will be equal to zero.

The second one assigns `result` to the function named `foo`. Now, `result` is not equal to zero; `result` is equal to the function `foo`.

Do you see the problem in your code now?

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout(this.testLoop(), 1000);` should be `setTimeout(this.testLoop, 1000);` as you want the function, not its return value.

Comment: Like a thief in the night you beat me to this while i was correcting typos.

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
setTimeout(this.testLoop(), 1000);
```

to

```
setTimeout(this.testLoop, 1000);
```